# Is this loop gain infinite?

Tags: loop-gain

Here is the circuit from this [youtube link](https://youtu.be/2cHCLKWC5hM?t=2376)

[image]

Break the loop.
[image]

For M1, because there is no current through M1, so we have
$$\frac{V_y - V_F} {r_{o1}} - V_F g_{m1} = 0$$
$$\frac{V_y} {V_F} = \frac{r_{o1}}  {(r_{o1} \parallel \frac{1} {g_{m1}})}$$

For M2,
$$V_x g_{m2} + \frac{V_{out}} {r_{o2}} = - \frac{V_{out}} {R_1 + R_2}$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_{out}} {V_x} = - g_{m2} \bigr(r_{o2} \parallel (R_1 +R_2) \bigr)$$

$$V_F = V_{out} \frac{R_1} {R_1 + R_2}$$

$$\frac{V_y} {V_x} = \frac{V_y} {V_F} \frac{V_F} {V_x} = - \frac{r_{o1}}  {(r_{o1} \parallel \frac{1} {g_{m1}})} g_{m2} \bigr(r_{o2} \parallel (R_1 +R_2) \bigr)$$

However, the lecturer from [youtube link](https://youtu.be/2cHCLKWC5hM?t=2376) said the following.
$$\frac{V_y} {V_x} = \infty$$

Comment: What is the voltage loop gain if \$r_{o1}\$ is infinite? You basically have a current source open which could develop an infinite voltage ideally.

Comment: @internet Why do you assume \$r_{o1}\$ is \$\infty\$? 
Where is my analysis wrong?

Comment: That is what I inferred from the video for loop gain to be infinity.

Comment: @internet Is there any mistake in my analysis?